# Pyspark multilabel text classification

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, databricks

I'm trying to predict labels for unknown text. My data looks like this:

```
+-----------------+-----------+
|      label      |   text    |
+-----------------+-----------+
| [0, 1, 0, 1, 0] | blah blah |
| [1, 1, 0, 0, 0] | foo bar   |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

First column encoded using multi label binarization approach.
My pipeline:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(), outputCol="features")
lsvc = LinearSVC(maxIter=10, regParam=0.1)
ovr = OneVsRest(classifier=lsvc)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, hashingTF, ovr])

model = pipeline.fit(result)
```

When I run this code, I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]'
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: how did you generate label column. I am doing something very similar and I am not able to find an equivalent of MultilableBinarizer in pyspark. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error

> invalid literal for int()

We see that the problem is that the expected type of the label is not an array, but a single value corresponing to the class of the sample. In other words, you need to convert the label from  multi label binarization encoding to a single number.

One way to do it is by first converting the array to a string and then use a [`StringIndexer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#stringindexer):

```
to_string_udf = udf(lambda x: ''.join(str(e) for e in x), StringType())
df = df.withColumn("labelstring", to_string_udf(df.label))

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="labelstring", outputCol="label")
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

This will make a separate category (class label) for each unique array.

Comment: Wouldn't this affect accuracy? With this approach we predict corpus of labels instead of individual labels

Comment: @KertisvanKertis: Could be, but as far as I know there isn't really much choice if you want to use PySpark here. If the dataset is smaller you could try `sklearn` which do have methods that support this type of labeling.